# Time and conditional statement is not working in python?

Tags: python-2.7

What the purpose of this file is for, is to switch a Boolean to false when the time (EST) is between 8 AM-11 PM.

```
import time as t
from datetime import datetime
while True:
t.sleep(1)
current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
current_hour = datetime.now().strftime('%H')
print current_hour
if 23 > current_hour:
    print 'Sleep mode activated (1)'
    sleep_mode = True
elif current_hour < 7:
    print 'Sleep mode activied (2)'
    sleep_mode = True
else:
    sleep_mode = False
```

The problem, however is here:

```
if 23 > current_hour:
    print 'Sleep mode activated (1)'
    sleep_mode = True
```

It returns true even if I change '23' to an unrealistic number, or a time in which is MUCH greater than the current time.

I've also tested to make sure that its working in EST; which it is. I don't know if theres something wrong with the if statement or something. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

You should never do this:

```
current_hour = datetime.now().strftime('%H')
```

If you want the current hour, just use:

```
current_hour = datetime.now().hour
```

You are converting a `datetime` to a string, then extracting part of that string and trying to compare it to a different data type.  **Don't. Do. That.**  Python's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module has wonderful properties, like [hour](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.hour) - just use them.

Answer (score 0):

`23 > current_hour` is equivalent to `current_hour < 23`, which will usually be true (except for one hour in the day). If you make `23` into something MUCH greater, like `100`, then it will *always* return true. I think you wanted to say `23 < current_hour` (or `current_hour > 23`); this is closer, but hours never go above `23`, so... `23 <= current_hour` is actually what you want (or the equivalent `current_hour >= 23`).

Comment: `if 23 < current_hour:
        print 'Sleep mode activated (1)'
        sleep_mode = True` didn't work. Right now, I'm using military time and its 21 hours. The section statement checks if its midnight to 7 AM.